# How to use : colon char in Bottle route

Tags: bottle

I have simple Bottle route, and URL should contain `:` (colon) sign. URL should be like `/REST/item:128` or `/REST/item:89753`

My route is

```
@route('/REST/item:<id:int>')
def icc(id):
    return { 'id': id }
```

Route is not working properly. `id` contain only last char from url id, not full id.

How to use `:` (colon) in route?

Comment: I'm not sure that a colon `:` is even legal in a URL path. See [RFC 2396](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-3).

Comment: From RFC - `Authors should be aware that a path segment which contains a colon character cannot be used as the first segment of a relative URI path (e.g., "this:that"), because it would be mistaken for a scheme name.`. So I think it's not an absolute deny.

Comment: Here is an example on colon in URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Welcome. Yes, usage is not a proof, but it's a common practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this was confusing.

I haven't had time to fully understand what's happening, but I suspect that one of Bottle's route regexes is eating too many characters when there's a colon in the route.

In any case, escaping the colon with a backslash appears to solve the problem:

```
@route(r'/REST/item\:<id_:int>')  # note the "r" prefix there
def icc(id_):
    return {'id': id_}
```

Here's a test request and its response:

```
=> curl -v 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/REST/item:123'
{"id": 123}
```

---

**EDIT**: Mystery [solved](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/976#issuecomment-307455443).

> Bottle currently supports two syntaxes for url wildcards: The 
>   one (since 0.10) and the :old syntax. Both are described here:
>   http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html
>
> In your example, the : triggered the old syntax. The solution is to
>   escape the colon with a backslash (as described in the SO answer).
>   Escaping is fully implemented and works as intended, but is
>   undocumented. This is why I leave this issue open. Pull requests for
>   better documentation would be welcomed.

Comment: Yes, I've check it and looks working. Thank you! How do you think - it could be an error in Bottle?

Comment: Happy it helped! It could be a subtle regex error in Bottle, yes.

Comment: Wrote to authors. https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/976 Seems like Bottle is not very active project now :(

Comment: Marcel Hellkamp was answered on github

Comment: Nice! I've updated the answer to include his explanation.

Comment: Doc for Bottle was updated https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/pull/979 by `pepelisu`.